# Match hyphenated word

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb

I'm trying to SELECT all rows that have an hyphenated word in a certain column. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE list RLIKE '\w-\w'
```

But it's only returning 1 row, when I know there are a lot more. Any ideas why?

Thank you

```
| List |
built-in
self-discipline
hang-up
....
```

EDIT: Not sure if it matters, but *list* is utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: what does it look like in the database?

Comment: @JohnRuddell What do you mean?

Comment: what does the actual string look like?

Comment: so why use regex? why not just `WHERE list LIKE "%-%"` ?

Comment: @JohnRuddell because then I get this too: '-to'; 'high-'; etc

Comment: not sure if I follow your last comment.. is that something you dont want thats in your database? that the regex removes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL regular expressions don't support `\w` (or any other escape sequences for character classes). You must write:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE list RLIKE '[[:alnum:]_]-[[:alnum:]_]'
```

See the [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) for details of MySQL regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you. Was not aware that it did not support \w.

Comment: Doesn't anyone check the documentation BEFORE posting to SO?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to try and use it without regex then try the wildcard.. not sure if you are not able to use that or not, but that should work too

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE list LIKE '%-%'
```